# AWS AppSync RDS: $util.rds.toJSONObject() Nested Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

I am using Amazon RDS with AppSync. I've created a resolver that join two tables to get One-to-One association between them and returns columns from both tables. What I would like to do is to be able to put nest some columns under a key in the resulting parsed JSON object evaluated using $util.rds.toJSONObject().

Here's the schema:

```
type Parent {
    col1: String
    col2: String
    child: Child
}

type Child {
    col3: String
    col4: String
}
```

Here's the resolver:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "SELECT parent.*, child.col3 AS `child.col3`, child.col4 AS `child.col4` FROM parent LEFT JOIN child ON parent.col1 = child.col3"
    ]
}
```

I tried naming the resulting column with dot-syntax but, **$util.rds.toJSONObject()** doesn't put `col3` and `col4` under `child` key. The reason it should is because otherwise, Apollo won't be able to cache and parse the entity.

**Note:** Dot-syntax is not documented anywhere. Usually, some ORMs use dot-syntax technique to convert SQL rows to proper nested JSON objects.

Comment: `$util.rds.toJsonObject()` Transforms an RDS sql result to a friendlier format - a JSON object. It is not a full-fledged ORM. You will need to write this custom logic yourself. You can manipulate the output of `$util.rds.toJSONObject()` as a List of Maps with String Keys and Object values. Also, what is the expected output type that is attached to that resolver? (Is it a List of Parents?)

Comment: I resorted to AWS Lambda Resolvers that used `sequelize` to query and return data. Works really well. I can easily query relationships in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

The @Aaron_H comment and answer were useful for me, but the response mapping template provided in the answer didn't work for me.
I managed to get a working response mapping template for my case which is similar for the case in question. In images below you will find info for query -> message(id: ID) { ... } (one message and the associated user will be returned):

1. SQL request to `user` table;
2. SQL request to `message` table;
3. SQL JOIN tables request for message id=1;
4. GraphQL Schema;
5. Request and response templates;
6. AWS AppSync query.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

https://github.com/xai1983kbu/apollo-server/blob/pulumi_appsync_2/bff_pulumi/graphql/resolvers/Query.message.js

---

**Next example for query messages**

[image]
[image]
[image]

https://github.com/xai1983kbu/apollo-server/blob/pulumi_appsync_2/bff_pulumi/graphql/resolvers/Query.messages.js

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your resolver is expecting to return a list of Parent types, ie. `[Parent!]!`, you can write your response mapping template logic like this:

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

#set($output = $utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0])

## Make sure to handle instances where fields are null
## or don't exist according to your business logic

#foreach( $item in $output )
    #set($item.child = {
        "col3": $item.get("child.col3"),
        "col4": $item.get("child.col4")
    })
#end

$util.toJson($output)
```